# Dracut-Kernel update required but won't when running Yum on Centos 6.6

Tags: linux, centos, yum, dracut

I'm a fair newbie when it comes to Linux, but I'm having problems updating a small Centos 6.6 box that's been working fine and updating previously.

When running yum update I get the error below. I've tried running yum -clean all as per another post on a similar issue but that hasn't helped.

```
--> Processing Dependency: dracut-kernel >= 004-388.el6 for package: kernel-2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kernel-2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: dracut-kernel >= 004-388.el6
           Installed: dracut-kernel-004-256.el6.noarch (@anaconda-CentOS-201112091719.x86_64/6.2)
               dracut-kernel = 004-256.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum clean had been tried (as detailed in my original post) but didn't help.

I eventually found a line exclude=dracut in yum.conf which is bizarre as I certainly didn't put it there and only I have access to the machine.  I presume something has automatically added it for some reason, but problem solved now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a yum clean all, that should sort it

It seems this has been a fairly common problem when upgrading from 6.6 to 6.7